# Crystal Report crosstab calculation rounding up to whole number

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a report with a crosstab that displays a count of the number of records for given categories for each of the previous 6 quarters. I’ve inserted a calculated member column for the average for those 6 counts for each category. The problem that I’m having is that the average is being rounded or possibly trunkated to an integer, even when I specify Decimal as ‘1.000’ and Rounding as ‘1.000’ under Format Editor>Number>Custom Style. I tested this by multiplying the formula by 100: For a value that should be 4.5, the formula displays 4.0 without multiplying by 100, and 450 when it is multiplied by 100. I think that there must be some basic configuration setting that I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports rounds up from two decimal places by default. Try to specify your rounding setting in the opposite direction, like in the image below:

[image: CR snapshot]

Let me know if that works or if you still have the issue.